# Space between anchor tag href and title attributes in profile gets removed upon display

Tags: support, status-completed, hyperlinks, profile-page

The space between href and title in anchor tag in profile gets removed when the profile html is edited; subsequent save will cause the html to be invalid and the tags will get stripped out.  The initial save works and the anchor tag displays properly.  This is only a problem if you edit your profile and forget to put the space between the title and href attributes back in.

Steps to repro:

- Edit your profile.
- Enter this line of html:

> ```
> <a href="http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids" title="Jeff Widmer's Blog">My Blog</a>
> ```

- Save your profile
- Go back and edit profile
- Notice that space between href and title is gone:

> ```
> <a href="http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids"title="Jeff Widmer's Blog">My Blog</a>
> ```

- Now if you hit save the anchor tag is invalid and the html will get stripped out.

Comment: Totally able to reproduce

Comment: Yes. I reproduced this behavior too.

Answer (score 1):

If you leave off the `TITLE` attribute it works fine. Do you have to have the tooltip float like the flutterby?

The parser for the bio is probably just not wanting to allow you to have that attribute and just removing any suspect whitespace in the opening anchor tag. Resulting in the jamming of it all into a nice and unworkable link.

Answer (score 0):

This had to do with removing `rel="nofollow"` when it was between two other attributes and not at the beginning or end.